# Graphical proof of CV, CS, EV comparison for inferior goods

Tags: microeconomics

I've seen this intuitive graphical proof of why EV < CS < CV for normal goods which interprets the integrals as areas under the respective curves (see below). Can you also do this for inferior goods to show EV > CS > CV?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a good is inferior the Marshallian demand function will be steeper than the Hiсksian demand funсtion (it may even slope upwards if it is a Giffen good), this result comes directly from applying the definition of an inferior good to the Slutsky equation. Thus, the intersection of $h_1^1$ and $P_1^0$ will be to the right of $x_1^0$, while the intersection of $h_1^0$ and $P_1^1$ will be to the left of $x_1^1$. Thus, $h_1^0$ will be to the left of $h_1^1$ and they won't intersect. Hence, $EV > CS > CV$.